# How to group by a certain column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, grouping

I have a SQL table that looks like this

[image]

I'd like to group by System to show if all tasks are done or not (if all statuses for a system are done then Done else Not Done).

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: And https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `MAX()` with `GROUP BY`. Assuming those are the only two available values for your status column.

```
SELECT Name, System, MAX(Status) Status
FROM Table
GROUP BY Name, System
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, this would work perfectly fine with OP's given data. MAX() will always work in this case, since it looks like 'Not Done' cannot come before 'Done', because you cannot 'Setup Permissions' before you 'Create Account', therefore 'Not Done' is always greater alphabetically. But if that is not the case, you will need a CASE statement.

Comment: @Simon, I was a little confused myself. I did add a disclaimer - "Assuming those are the only two values..." Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @bjones No problem, I equalized the vote. I think the DV was (unfortunately) from something petty like downvoting answerer for answering a relative 'easy' to find, answer or poorly written question.

Answer (score 0):

Select Distinct Name/System, and then use a subquery for the Status.

The subquery could be a CASE WHEN EXISTS() structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Name,
    System, 
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT NULL AS [Empty] FROM Table AS t_inner WHERE t_inner.Status = 'Not Done' AND t_inner.System = t_outter.System AND t_inner.Name = t_outter.Name) EXISTS 
        THEN 'Not Done'
        ELSE 'Done'
    END
FROM
    Table AS t_outter
```